# Proof of a norm for expression

Tags: normed-spaces

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

For $1 \leq p<\infty$ , prove that $\|x\|_{p}=\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left|x_{k}\right|^{p}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}$ is a norm on $l^p$ .

Comment: Please, help me solve this problem.

Comment: It's only available in pretty much every single textbook on functional analysis or on real analysis...

Comment: Could you please send me an example of solution?